# freeCodeCamp Product landing page testing error, cannot find error

Tags: html, css

I am doing the freecodecamp workthroughs and it hit an error in the script that tests the product landing page project I'm working on.

Problem is as follows:

When I click a `.nav-link` button in the `nav` element, I am taken to the corresponding section of the landing page.

However, my code as far as I can tell, does exactly that.

What in my code is causing this error?

[My code, JS test hamburger hidden in logo in top left](https://codepen.io/kylefurby/pen/rRXLej)

Thanks for the help.

```
<header>
       <div id="header">
               <img id="header-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/KIqkWAZ.png" alt="handbooker helper logo"/>
           <nav id="nav-bar">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#infoLinks">Episodes</a>
               <a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a>
               <a class="nav-link" href="https://critrole.com/">More from Critical Role</a>
           </nav>
       </div>
   </header>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: it has a javascript file that tests user stories. The story i cannot pass says the following:

"When I click a .nav-link button in the nav element, i am taken to the corresponding section of the landing page'"

which when i click nav buttons up top on my page it directs me to different sections of the page. so i cannot figure out why i cannot pass that story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the script assumes all your nav-links correspond to a target on the same page, there's no way you can pass that story.

I tried it by replacing the link

```
href="https://critrole.com/"
```

with href="#test" and creating a div with id test, and the story passed after doing so.

Comment: so the story is just expecting me to link to sections on the page. I didn't figure it would break with links. Especially since it says that it requires at least 1 not all 3.

Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @kylefurby Yeah i believe that's the issue, as the error states `The .nav-link with href="https://critrole.com/" is not linked to a corresponding element on the page` which makes it pretty clear that it expects all your links to link to a section on your page. Remember to mark as answer if that solved your question. No problem

Comment: Makes sense. Once I changed it to link to another section instead of the link it worked right away.